# Is it okay to use a flexible json attribute type? array vs object based on the amount of items?

Tags: json, payment-gateway

i'm trying to integrate our application with a payment providers. There API uses both Arrays and Objects on the same json property.

Example: 
When getting the Shoppingcart with cart-items, the response will be like this when there is one cart-item:

GET /cart/{cart-identifier}

```
{
  "cart_identifier": 1,
  "items": {
    "product_identifier": 2,
    "amount": 1
  } 
}
```

When there are 2 items in the cart, the response will be like this.

```
{
  "cart_identifier": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "product_identifier": 2,
      "amount": 1
    },
    {
      "product_identifier": 3,
      "amount": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

To me, this does not make sense, but does anyone know what the JSON specification says of this? And are there any good reasons to do it this way? 
Ps: If you have some good blog posts that are related to this then please send me a message.

Comment: That's unnecessary. It's okay to have an array with one element. So define the structure as such so ti is consistent and predictable (and easier to implement).

Answer (score 0):

As far as the JSON specification is concerned, both forms are correct. You may have problems if you try to map the JSON to a Java class though. This depends on what parser you're using.